# How to capture the screen except for some windows in UWP app?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm developing an screen recorder app with Media Capture API in UWP. Now I'm trying to make the application able to record the screen except the windows of my application.I have heard that Magnification API can help me to do this if I develop the application in Win32 environment,but how to do this in UWP and Media Capture API?

Comment: Does the following could solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> How to capture the screen except for some windows in UWP app?

Starting in Windows 10, **version 1803**, the `Windows.Graphics.Capture` namespace provides APIs to acquire frames from a display or application window.

You could  use the [`GraphicsCapturePicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.graphicscapturepicker) class to invoke the system picker UI. The end user uses this UI to select the display or application window of which to take screen captures. The picker will return a GraphicsCaptureItem that will be used to create a GraphicsCaptureSession.

Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture) that contains complete sample code.

Comment: Okay, I tried to build an app by using Windows.Graphics.Capture, but is it possible to capture multiple windows rather than whole screen with Windows.Graphics.Capture?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't capture multiple windows with `Windows.Graphics.Capture`, currently  it only support capture a single window once.

Comment: I found that SetWindowDisplayAffinity may help me, but I don't know how to call WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE, is it available in the latest Windows 10 SDK?

Comment: That‘s win32 api, it will not work in uwp platform.

Comment: I am building a WPF app that is using the Windows.Graphics.Capture. The capture function works well on my WPF app. The blog on below says WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE will be added in SetWindowDisplayAffinity. Is it possible to use it in my WPF app? https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/09/16/new-ways-to-do-screen-capture/